# Secure a password change form

Tags: php, security, hash, bcrypt, change-password

When an admin manually changes a user's password, they need to type (or generate) the password into an HTML input which is then submitted to PHP.

How would I secure a input that is purpose is for secure passwords, which means special/html characters such as '>', '#', '<', etc.

Previously, I used:

```
<?php htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($password)) ?>
```

But this was changing the password to something else, I'm guessing to the character entity format - I cannot see what it's changing it too, due to one-way hashing via bcrypt.

EDIT: For example, this is a password `*62mA<Edq<Kfx)3y` when I check the output of the above code, it outputs it to `*62mA`

Thanks

Comment: `strip_tags`? You're changing the users password/restricting them from using certain characters which I see as an immediate flaw.

Comment: And why would and Admin manually change user's password?

Comment: If the password is hashed (and it must be), then there's nothing to protect it from. But as already suggested - allowing admins to change user passwords is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Just don't (limit passwords). Both `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` take this into account. This is an answer in its own right. Passwords such as `<b>123'\DELETE` are considered as being perfectly valid.

Comment: Just remove `strip_tags` and you are good to go.

Comment: The OP should use no cleansing mechanism at all @Mario

Comment: @JayBlanchard If I understand him right he wants do print the password into an HTML document so he should absolutely use htmlspecialchars. I think Quentin's answer is point on.

Comment: An "HTML input" @Mario, not a document.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Well yes obviously...

Comment: @Mario the admin type the user password in html input to reset the password

Comment: I also can't see why you'd want to echo passwords in the form's input. [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is what that is mostly used for, and suggests it.

Comment: Okay thank you guys, I shall make these corrections, I must've misunderstood the PHP docs.

Answer (score 4):

There is no general purpose "make this data safe for every situation" tool. You need to use *situation appropriate* escaping.

**Do not** use destructive functions like `strip_tags`.

If you want to put it into an HTML document: **Do** use `htmlspecialchars`.

If you want to put it into an SQL database:  **Do** use prepared statement.

If you want to put it into JavaScript:  **Do** use `json_encode`.

… etc … etc.

The parser that deals with the data will decode any escape characters.

---

That said… **Do not** store passwords. **Do** [Hash passwords](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php). **Do**  [Protect passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: So a PDO prepared statement will be sufficient enough to secure that input?

Comment: It will be sufficient to safely insert it into a database without losing data. It won't help if you later insert it into an HTML document.